# Skim.app resets view on refresh

Tags: mac, viewers

There appears to be a bug in `OSX Sierra` that causes [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) to reset its view of a `PDF` on reload. This bug was [supposed to be fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/mailman/message/35551378/) with the `10.2.2 OSX` update, but hasn't.

When working on small laptop screen, I find it convenient to zoom the viewer into a particular part of the page. Recompiling the `TeX` file causes Skim to reload the file and reset the view to the top left of the page. This means repeatedly having to switch to Skim and scrolling in order to see the resulting changes.

Are there any workarounds, or good alternatives to `Skim.app` that support external editors (e.g., `Emacs`) and inverse search with `SyncTeX`?

The `TexShop` viewer doesn't exhibit the jump-on-reload bug, but doesn't seem to support inverse search with an external editor.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I've never seen this and I use Skim on Sierra all the time.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug is *not* present in Skim, at least as of the version I'm using (1.4.31) on Sierra (10.12.6).

Comment: As there isn't a “cannot reproduce” close option, I'm voting to close this as “unclear what you're asking” (following 3 others), because in [the linked thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/mailman/message/35551378/) the Skim developer says it's fixed, 3 days after the question was posted here.